# Find string with most characters in array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string

I have an array of string, and would like to find the index of the string with the most characters. I would like to do this without a for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the [`Select` overload that gives you the index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), order by descending length and get the first value;

```
string[] strings = new string[]{ "one", "three", "two" };

var value = strings.Select ((val, ix) => new {len=val.Length, ix})
                   .OrderByDescending (x => x.len).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine ("Index of longest string is: " +
                   (value != null ? value.ix : -1));
```

Comment: Nice. Completely forgot about that! Will remove my answer shortly. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function that takes a current string, the array of strings, the index of the current string, index of the current string in the array, and the current max char count.